# Issues getting my Spring Boot index page and controller mappings to work when returning JSP view name

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and JSP to learn some quick tutorials in Spring Security but my **controller mappings** and `index.jsp` are not working. It seems it can't locate the `JSP` pages. Here is my config and project structure:

```
springsecurity-for-reactive-apps [boot] - Project folder
  - src/main/java
    - com.springsecurity
      - SpringsecurityForReactiveAppsApplication.java
    - com.springsecurity.config
      - ApplicationConfig.java 
      - SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java
      - SpringMvcWebApplicationInitializer.java 
      - SpringSecurityConfig.java 
      - WebApplicationConfig.java 
  - src
    - main
      - webapp
        - WEB-INF
          - view
             - home.jsp
          - index.jsp
```

**com.springsecurity** package contains

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringsecurityForReactiveAppsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringsecurityForReactiveAppsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

com.springsecurity.config package contains the following classes

```
@Configuration
    public class ApplicationConfig {
         @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
          private String DB_DRIVER;

              @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
              private String DB_PASSWORD;

              @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
              private String DB_URL;

              @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
              private String DB_USERNAME;

            @Autowired
            private Environment env;

            @Bean
            public DataSource getDataSource() {
                DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
                dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
                dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
                dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
                dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
                return dataSource;
            }

        }
```

And `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` class is

```
        public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{
        }
```

`SpringMvcWebApplicationInitializer` class is

```
        public class SpringMvcWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
            @Override
            protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
                return new Class[] { WebApplicationConfig.class };
            }

            @Override
            protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected String[] getServletMappings() {
                return new String[] { "/" };
            }
        }
```

And my configuration class is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
        public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
            @Autowired
            private DataSource dataSource;
            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
                auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                    .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled"
                               + " from users where username = ?")
                    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority "
                               + "from authorities where username = ?")
                    .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                   http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                           .and()
                           .httpBasic(); // Use Basic authentication
               }
    }
```

And

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.springsecurity"})
    public class WebApplicationConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
        @Override
        public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
               registry.jsp().prefix("/WEB-INF/view/").suffix(".jsp");
           }

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
             InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
                viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
                viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
                viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
                return viewResolver;
        }

    }
```

**- com.springsecurity.controller** contains:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
       public String home(Model model, Principal principal) {
        System.out.println("___________home()___________________");
           return "home";
       }

    @GetMapping("/error")
       public String error(Model model, Principal principal) {
        System.out.println("___________ERROR-<<error___________________");
           return "home";
       }

}
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.springsecurity</groupId>
    <artifactId>springsecurity-for-reactive-apps</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>springsecurity-for-reactive-apps</name>
    <description>Spring security for reactive applications</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring dependencies START-->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
           </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
           </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
           </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
           </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
           </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet and JSP related dependencies -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.1</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
           <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
           <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For datasource configuration -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
           </dependency>
        <!-- We will be using MySQL as our database server -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>   
        <!-- Spring dependencies END -->        

</dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I go to **http://localhost:8080**, I get this page

```
 Whitelabel Error Page
    This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

    Thu Oct 18 03:24:51 CEST 2018
    There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
    No message available
```

The error page is mapped to show the `home.jsp` but I get the above page

Answer (score 0):

1.viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");  **views** -> **view**

2.you can implements ErrorController in spring

```
@Controller
public class ViewController implements ErrorController {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(Model model) {
     System.out.println("___________home()___________________");
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/error")
    public String error(Model model) {
     System.out.println("___________ERROR-<<error___________________");
        return "home";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml remove

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.1</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And add these dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

As I know, to render jsp page in boot `tomcat-embed-jasper` is needed.